# How to get an index in all cases of the same value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two arrays where one is to check the indexes and one is with values to check.

```
    var array = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 1000.0, 1800.0, 350.0, 336.0, 110.0, 1900.0, 130.0];
    var check = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 110.0, 130.0];
    var indeks = [];


for(var i = 0; i < check.length; i++){
     // Logger.log(check[i]);
     //indeks.push(array.indexOf(check[i]));

     function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}
indeks.push(getAllIndexes(array, check[i]));
    }
    Logger.log(indeks);
```

the output I am getting now is:
`[[0.0], [1.0, 2.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0, 4.0], [3.0], [8.0], [10.0]]`

I want to get output that looks like this:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10]`

I found `getAllIndexes` in another question here but somehow it doesn't work well and I am not sure where I am getting wrong.
When I use only `indeks.push(array.indexOf(check[i]))` I am getting this: `[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 8.0, 10.0]` which is pretty close to result I am looking for

If anyone know the solution I would be very gratefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 1000.0, 1800.0, 350.0, 336.0, 110.0, 1900.0, 130.0];
var check = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 110.0, 130.0];

function getUniqueIndexes(array, check) {
  // copy array to prevent mutation
  var arr = array.slice()

  // loop through `check`
  const indeks = check.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // find index of the current value
    var i = arr.indexOf(cur)
    if (i !== -1) {
      // erase the value to prevent further matches
      arr[i] = null
      // return the acumulator with the new index for each loop
      return [...acc, i]
    }
  }, [])

  return indeks
}

const indeks = getUniqueIndexes(array, check)
console.log(indeks)
// result should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10]
```

That's it ;)

*I'm not sure if this code is ES6 or not, maybe you will need to transpile it before use*

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code, like declaring the function inside the loop. When you used `indeks.push(array.indexOf(check[i]))`, you were super close to the answer. The reason it returned `indeks` as `[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 8.0, 10.0]` is because the function finds the index of `val` in the array, starting from the beginning. Therefore, if you have duplicate elements (in this case, yes), it only finds the first occurrence. I solved it by looking at [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#parameters). It says that indexOf also has an optional parameter called `fromIndex`. This is where you start searching the array. Using a `nums` array which I push to every time in the function. I take the length of `nums`, and pass it in as the `fromIndex` param. Hope that made sense, and here's the code:

```
var array = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 1000.0, 1800.0, 350.0, 336.0, 110.0, 1900.0, 130.0];
var check = [1200.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 110.0, 130.0];
var indeks = []; 
var nums = [];
var indexes = []; // Top Level (for scope)

    function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
      if (arr.indexOf(val, nums.length) > -1) {
        indexes.push(arr.indexOf(val, nums.length));
        nums.push("num")
      }
    }        

    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
      indeks.push(getAllIndexes(array, check[i]));
    }  
    console.log(indexes)
```